# JPA @Version Soft delete does not work when attempting to a deleted entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with optimistic locking. I have a class which has an @Version annotated field + soft delete

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "units_locks")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE units_locks SET active=false WHERE id=?")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
public class LockDbEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  protected Long id;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "entity_version")
  private long entityVersion;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Boolean active;
}
```

When I try delete the Entity, the Hibernite throws the following exception:

```
lockDbRepository.deleteAll(unitLockDbEntities);
```

> optimistic locking failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
> another transaction.

The interesting thing is that if I use a native query the mechanism works,

```
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "UPDATE units_locks SET active=false WHERE unit_id IN (:ids)", nativeQuery = true)
  void deleteAllNativeQuery(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

But it will force me to change my code quite a bit and that's why I want to solve the above problem.

I am using Hibernate  5.6.2 version

Answer (score 0):

This exception is expected if the row/object was changed in the meantime. Using a native query would simply skip the optimistic lock check.

But you have to ask yourself, is it legal to delete the row/object even if it was changed in the meantime? Maybe you have logic in your code that only allows deletion if the object is unused, which might now be violated.

Read a bit into optimistic locking to understand what the purpose of this mechanism is: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking